# Why my extend function is not working?

Tags: javascript, callback

extend is based on each function:

```
function each(collection,iterator) {
    if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
        for (var i=0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            iterator(collection[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for (var key in collection) {
            iterator(collection[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

after I check underscore.js, apparently the extend function takes two parameters...but im not sure how to rewrite the function so it can work?

```
function extend(newProperty) {
    each(arguments,function(source) {
        each(source,function(value,key) {
            newProperty[key]=value;
        })
    })
    return newProperty;
}

var iceCream = {flavor: "chocolate"};
extend(iceCream,{sprinkles: "lots"});
//==> { flavor: 'chocolate', undefined: 'chocolate' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `each` function is only providing the element of the collection, it should also provide the key.  Try this.

```
function each(collection,iterator) {
    if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
        for (var i=0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            iterator(collection[i], i);
        }
    } else {
        for (var key in collection) {
            iterator(collection[key], key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks@Steve Hansell and @Reece  . can you explain to be what's the difference between collection[key] and key? isn't collection[key] already points to the key in the object?

Comment: @Danny collection[key] points to the element of the object where key is the unique identifier within the object.

Comment: so if collection[key] already points to the element, why we need identifier key here? I don't understand why function(value,key) takes two parameter, isn't value represents collection[key] already, why take an extra key here?

Comment: @Danny `key` holds a string identifier e.g. "flavor", I think u understand that.  So why does the function take two parameters?  The first is the actual element: 'collection[key]', I think you got that.  The second is the 'key' and it must be provided simply because the innermost `each` in `extend` takes a callback as the second arg, and this arg takes **two** args, the first being the element and the second the key to extend on `newProperty`

Comment: when we say 'collection[key]' is the element in a object, do we mean it is {flavor: 'chocolate'} or just 'chocolate'?

Comment: @Danny in your example `flavor` is the key and `"chocolate"` is the element. The expression `chocolate[key]` points to the element identified as whatever `key` is (some string), in our case the key is `"flavor"` and the element is  `"chocolate"`. 